# Не пересоздается файл после удаления до перезагрузки системы

Tags: android

Есть некий код, который при старте приложения делает так:

```
String FILE_NAME = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +  "/file.txt";

fw = new FileWriter(FILE_NAME, true);
fw.append("foo");
fw.flush();
```

Изначально файла file.txt на диске нет. После запуска приложения файл создается и в него пишется строка. Закрываем приложение и открываем его снова - в файл добавляется еще одна строка. Пока все хорошо. Теперь файл удаляется и приложение запускается снова. Файл не создается. Исключений при этом нет. Последующие перезапуски приложения к созданию файла не приводят. Перезагружаем андроид и все снова работает. Куда копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подозреваю, что приложение каким-то образом выживает между запусками (мне тут не видно, откуда именно происходит запуск), а значит хендл на файл продолжает жить даже после удаления файла. Вот в удаленный файл вы и пишите.

В линуксе (а андроид - это такой дистрибутив линукса) вы не удаляете файл, вы лишь удаляете его имя. Даже системный вызов называется unlink. Физическое удаление происходит лишь в тот момент, когда удалены не только все имена, но и закрыты все хендлы, которые использовали этот файл.

Для начала можно попробовать добавить:

```
fw.close();
```

Comment: По-любому поток нужно закрыть, а не надеяться что система сама догадается освободить открытый с потоком файл-дескриптор.

Comment: Да, замена flush на close решило проблему. Спасибо.